# Is it possible to permute an unknown binary sequence so that two particular bits are equal?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

A blind mathematician is give a $2015$ bit sequence. The mathematician can take any two bits and switch them (so the bit in position $A$ goes to position $B$ and vice-versa). He knows at what position they are and has really good memory, but he has never seen any of them. Can the mathematician do a certain number of steps (at each time he can select which bits he wants to switch) so that he can point at two bits and be absolutely sure they are equal?

This is from the $2015$ USA TST.

Comment: I like the new word you invented, inuntuitive.  I assume it means "unintuitive, but in a weird way."

Comment: ... are you sure you don't mean that two bits *have been equal* at some point during all the swappings?  Or perhaps the exercise stops if the two bits he grabs are equal?  Or perhaps he is allowed to toggle the bits he grabs?

Comment: I mean, my brain is telling me unequivocally that the answer is no, it's impossible. My argument for this is that after doing whatever moves you like any combination is still possible. In other words, the result after any number of movements is just a permutation of the initial word, so the possibilities for the sequence are literally all the bit-sequences

Comment: @vadim123 no, that would be trivial. You can go through all possible permutations of the word and then you can guarantee every pair of bits will have had the same value at some time.

Comment: Here is the original wording: A physicist encounters 2015 atoms called usamons. Each usamon either has one electron or zero electrons, and the physicist can't tell the difference. The physicist's only tool is a diode. The physicist may connect the diode from any usamon A to any other usamon B. (This connection is directed.) When she does so, if usamon A has an electron and usamon B does not, then the electron jumps from A to B. In any other case, nothing happens. In addition, the physicist cannot tell whether an electron jumps during any given step.

Comment: The physicist's goal is to isolate two usamons that she is sure are currently in the same state. Is there any series of diode usage that makes this possible?

Comment: What is the most believable ? That there is actually a way, or that the test team was troll-y enough to ask this and wait for the answer "no" ? :)

Comment: I mean, I am 100% certain it is no. I think what I gave is a proof of this. If I had seen this problem say in school or something I would immediately say you can't. I just looked at the solution and it turns out you can¿t. But I was completely flabbergasted that this was number $3$ in the USA TST.

Comment: The original problem is different from the one in the question.  In the question, the bits always switch.  In the original they only switch if $A=1, B=0$  I believe the answer to this question is no.

Comment: Couldn't we simply measure the quantity of information we want him to get at the end (1 bit), and compare it to the quantity of information he has at the beginning (0 bit) ?

Comment: @RossMillikan Right, that's the key: "this connection is directed."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have translated the problem incorrectly.

If A has an electron and B does not, then the electron jumps from A to B.

This is completely different from just swapping two bits!

The swap only happens when Bit A is 1, and bit B is 0, and you can designate which bit is A and which bit is B.

For that, seems like a bubble sort type of approach will do (just an idea, that is).

Comment: Username relevant.

Comment: swapping to equal bits is the same as not swapping them for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @Jorge: If A is 0 and B is 1, the swap will not happen.

Comment: Oh, you are right.

Comment: You can certainly do a sort, but that doesn't solve the problem by itself - depending on the count of on bits in the original string, the 'dividing line' between `1` bits and `0` bits can be at an arbitrary place in the resulting string.

Comment: If we restrict the problem to input sequences in which there are at least two of each value (i.e. all sequences of 1's and 0's which have at least two 1's and at least two 0's) then it becomes possible.

Answer (score 12):

For your question, the answer is no.  The output string is a known permutation of the input string.  If we could say two given bits were equal at the end, we could reverse the permutation and say two given bits were equal at the beginning, which we cannot.

Comment: yeah, that's what I thoug, although I seem to have copied the problem wrong.

Comment: I think the answer is no for the original problem as well, but haven't figured out how to prove it.

Comment: I have an idea for the original problem. Briefly, consider the bit representations of $p_i=2^i$ (all zeros and one one) and of $q_i=2^{2015}-2^i$ (all ones and one zero). At the start, no pair of positions $(r,k)$ has matching bits for all these. After each move, if $p_i$ becomes matching at $(r,k)$, $q_i$ becomes non-matching there, and vice versa. No matter what the sequence of moves, some $p_i$ or $q_i$ as initial configuration will foil the blind mathematician.

Comment: A slight correction to the previous comment: $q_i$ (all ones and one zero) is the bit sequence of $2^{2015}-1-2^i$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the bits are given to you already sorted (This problem is not harder).

label the bits $b_1,b_2\dots b_{2015}$ where $b_1\leq b_2\dots \leq b_{2015}$

So that the  sequence is $b_1b_2\dots b_{2015}$

To make a move the mathematician must select position $A$ and position $B$,so that if $A$ is $1$ and $B$ is zero they swap, and nothing happens otherwise.

At the start the mathematician has the bits ordered, so if the bit at position $A$ is $b_k$ and the bit at position $B$ is $b_n$ with $k<n$ he may safely assume that nothing has happened. Why? If the digits $(A,B)$ are $(1,1),(0,0)$ or $(0,1)$ the outcome will be the same as if nothing had happened, if they are $(1,0)$ then something will change, but notice this is impossible since $k<n$ and the bits are ordered.

I the other case if $k>n$ he can safely assume the swap did occur. Because if the bits are $(0,0),(1,0)$ or $(1,1)$ the outcome is the same as if the swap had indeed occured. The only case where it is different is $(0,1)$ but this cannot happpen because $k>n$.

So after each step he can be sure the current state of the sequence is going to be a specific permutation of $b_1b_2\dots b_k$ which he knows completely. So suppose there comes a time when the mathematician can be sure two bits are equal, he knows which of those two bits they are from the beginning, suppose they are $b_k$ and $b_l$. He then knows $b_k$ and $b_l$ are equal with $k<l$, from here he can assume that the number of zeros is not $k$ since otherwise $b_k$ would be the largest zero, and $b_l$ would be a one. But there is no way we could have deduced there are not $k$ zeros.

Comment: Note that in general we can't reverse the process, but when they are ordered at first we can do it.

Comment: When I say that we can fully expect the outcome I mean that when we send an electron from $b_r$ to $b_k$ with $r<k$ we know that nothing will happen. And on the other hand, when $r>k$ we can safely assume the value $b_r$ has been switched with the value of $b_k$

Comment: Jorge: This is a clever way to look at the problem, but I'm not convinced you have the right answer. The process is not reversible in the following sense: Suppose you enter the room after the mathematician applies just the first diode, and you notice that the sequence of bits is $0111\dots1$. What was the original sequence before the diode was applied? It’s impossible to know.

Comment: well yes, but in this case the mathematician knows which where the "coordinates" of the diodes he did, what I mean is that he can reverse his own process.

Comment: The blind mathematician can reverse his steps, but doing so won’t necessarily restore the original sequence of bits. Can you be more precise about how we have come to know that $b_r=b_k$? Why can’t the mathematician says “I know these two bits are identical *now*, but I don’t know which two positions they were originally in, because I don’t know which of my moves caused something to happen.”

Comment: Hmm, what I mean is the following: The mathematician starts with the ordered sequence $b_1,b_2,b_3\dots b_{2015}$. In the first move if he sends an electron from $b_r$ to $b_k$ with $r<k$ he knows that the sequence will stay the same. so the sequence is still $b_1,b_2\dots b_{2015}$. if $r>k$ he knows that the sequence is going to be the same as the sequence when $b_r$ and $b_k$ are switched (because the only possibilities are $b_r=b_k=1$ or $b_r=1,b_k=0$. In both cases the string becomes the string when $b_r$ is switched with $b_k$ and everything stays the same.

Comment: By induction the sequence will always be a permutation of the $b$'s. So if after a number of steps he can determine the bit at position $m$ is the same as the one in position $n$ he knows that those bits correspond to $b_k$ and $b_r$ for example(wlog $k<r$). and then he knows that the number of zeroes is not $k$ (since otherwise they would be different).

Comment: My point is that he can safely assume the swap was done when $r>k$ and he can safely assume the swap was not done when $r<k$. Because the sequence will be the same. (Of course it is possible the swap didn't actually occur, but for all intents and purposes we can assume it did, since the outcome would be the same).

Comment: I think you're on to something, but unfortunately, I have a meeting to go to. :( I look forward to an airtight answer from you when I get back!

Comment: I editted it, is it convincing now?

Answer (score 2):

Several commenters say you’ve misquoted a contest problem. But regardless, you asked a question that has an answer, and the answer is no.

Call the bits of the original sequence $b_i$, so the original word is $b_1b_2\dots b_{2015}$. A transposition $b_i\leftrightarrow b_j$ turns the sequence into the sequence  $b_{\tau(1)}b_{\tau(2)}\dots b_{{\tau(2015)}}$, where $\tau$ is the function that swaps $i$ and $j$ and leaves every other number alone.

After any number transpositions has been applied, the cumulative effect is that the original sequence has been turned into $b_{\sigma(1)}b_{\sigma(2)}\dots b_{{\sigma(2015)}}$, where $\sigma$ is a permutation of the set $\{1,2,\dots,2015\}$.

What’s key here is that because $\sigma$ is a permutation, it’s undoable (invertible). If the mathematician can say for sure that $b_{\sigma(i)}=b_{\sigma(j)}$, it must have been the case that two specific bits in the original sequence were equal (the bits $b_{\sigma^{-1}(i)}$ and $b_{\sigma^{-1}(j)}$, which were in the positions that were eventually swapped around to be in positions $i$ and $j$). But the mathematician can’t have known that those or any two bits in the original sequence were equal.

In the contest problem commenters say you misquoted, the mathematician applies transformations to the bits that can actually overwrite one of them, not just swap their positions. This is a requirement (but not an assurance) for the answer to such a puzzle to be “yes.” Otherwise, whatever the mathematician does is completely undoable, and the answer has to be no if any original sequence was possible.

*Added:* Actually, I’m not sure now whether overwriting is a requirement for the answer to be yes. See my comment below.

Comment: Thanks, although the original problem is doable if we know there are at least two $0$ digits.

Comment: In the original problem there is no overwrite, just an optional (depending on what the bits are) swap.  In particular, the number of $1$ bits in the string is constant.

Comment: If there were a sequence of diode applications that guaranteed that the mode of the bits ended up in the leftmost position, then it would be known that the leftmost two bits were equal. This is an interesting question - is there a sequence of conditional swaps (with the same condition $A>B$ every time) to sort a sequence of numbers in increasing order if there are more $0$s and in decreasing order if there are more $1$s? I suspect not, but I don’t know.

Comment: I posted a solution, could you comment please? thank you.